# Nested array formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I want a summation of rates. Let me explain it: I would like to sum the numbers in column D that matches 2 conditions (green rows in excel). First one: column F equal to "closed". Second one: column C equal to those numbers which in turn matches the following condition: column F equal to "Partial Sold". At the same time, EACH number in the previous summation might be divided by the number of column D which matches "Partial Sold" in column F. 
There is the example with the table/figure I attached: (4510 / 9820) + (6500 / 9820) + (9100 / 15400) + (2388 / 2995) + (12400 / 9820) + (2904 / 5855).
My cells would be: (D69 / D66) + (D70 / D66) + (D76 / D74) + (D82 / D78) + (D83 / D66) + (D84 / D72).

@Jeeped with your cells would be: (D6 / D3) + (D7 / D3) + (D13 / D11) + (D19 / D15) + (D20 / D3) + (D21 / D9)

```
..     C      D        E           F

65     #     Total    Side    Condition
66     1     9820     Buy     Partial Sold
67     2     3850     Buy     Closed
68     3     7151     Buy     Partial Sold
69     1     4510     Sell    Closed
70     1     6500     Sell    Closed
71     4     8180     Buy     Open
72     5     5855     Buy     Partial Sold
73     6     2553     Buy     Open
74     7     15400    Buy     Partial Sold
75     2     4600     Sell    Closed
76     7     9100     Sell    Closed
77     8     7531     Buy     Open
78     9     2995     Buy     Partial Sold
79     3     3000     Sell    Closed
80     10    8691     Buy     Open
81     3     2500     Sell    Closed
82     9     2388     Sell    Closed
83     1     12400    Sell    Closed
84     5     2904     Sell    Closed
85     11    3848     Buy     Open
86     12    7745     Buy     Open
```

Comment: to improve our answers, we right now need to know if there is a chance multiple lines hold the same # and "Partial Sold" and if yes, how to treat them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do it in one step with an array formula you could use:

```
=SUM(IFERROR((D66:D86*(F66:F86="Closed"))/((C66:C86=TRANSPOSE(C66:C86))*TRANSPOSE(D66:D86*(F66:F86="Partial Sold"))),0))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

it will generate a 2D-array holding the original values for closed as rows and divides this 1D array by this:

- buils up 2D-array by col C = transposed col C
- multiply each row by col D
- set all items in each row to 0 if not "Partial Sold"

for each div by 0 the `IFERROR` will set it to 0
and this all in the `SUM` will give you your output

[image]

Comment: If OP does not have `AGGREGATE` function as stated in @Jeeped answer, will he have `IFERROR()`?

Comment: My version of the formula: `=SUM(IFERROR((F66:F86="Closed")*(D66:D86/SUMIFS(D66:D86,F66:F86,"Partial Sold",C66:C86,C66:C86)),0))`

Comment: Scott, I do have iferror function. Dirk,Brak brilliant solutions. Sometimes you need someone who think out of the vos. I was too submerged on theproblem to even think different. Thanks again!

Comment: it was made while i didn't know he may not have functions like this. Also I would not recommend this with bigger tables cus it may freeze excel for several seconds to minutes or even crash when done for whole columns. **Better use a helper column to split everything up like jeeped mentioned!**

Comment: Yep, it was my fault. Anyway, thanks for complete the question and the answer. Then in order to preclude crashing would be preferable to split the thing. By now I would use the matrix foprmula. But the point now is what is more efficient, Dirk or Brak solution? I know the result is the same, but does they even perform the same thing?

Comment: I've run into a problem where if there are more than a single *Partial Sold* (column F) per **#** (column C), there will be problems. This is why I resorted to divide by a MATCH on column C (find first) rather than an array condition.

Comment: @Federico just by looks, I'd say the formula of BrakNicku should be much faster then my formula... but you should test it with bigger tables just to ensure my "feeling" is correct.

Comment: @Jeeped thanks for that comment, because actually it would be possible that exist more than one Partial Sold. In such a way, formula propose by Brak would works correctly, right? Anyone see any problem with formula posed by BrakNicku?

Comment: @Federico - Brak still uses a `SUMIFS($D$66:$D$86,$F$66:$F$86,"Partial Sold",$C$66:$C$86,$C$66:$C$86)` which would sum the **totals** from column D for the multiple matches.

Comment: @DirkReichel - If I change row 74 (just under **7 | 2553 | Buy | Partial Sold**) to **7 | 15400 | Buy | Partial Sold** I get a different answer. Unless that is the point; I had interpreted the original narrative to mean that you divided by the first match, not a collective one.

Comment: @Federico can you give us another example of the simplified (x / y) + (a / b) in a dummy case where you have multiple "Partial Sold" values for a single "#" value? I'm not exactly sure how you want it to behave in that scenario.

Comment: @DirkReichel I'm not sure if any of the results you provided in your last comment is correct. Didn't check it, but I think Jeeped's solution will give yet another result. The question is vague, so I didn't post it as an answer, cause we still don't know what the expected result should be.

Comment: @DirkReichel your comment (you deleted) had a point, I thought our formulas are equivalent, but you proved they are not, but we still do not know what is the required outcome. OP needs to clarify what to do in case there are multiple entries with same C column number.

Comment: it only occurs if there are multiple "Partial Sold"... which should not happen... we still need anything from the OP regarding this...

Comment: Hey guys, I'm using Brak formula. Multiple "Partial Sold" IS possible. I got the same result with Jeeped solution because it consists in divide the problem adding a column. If multiple "Partial Sold" were not possible, then Dirk approach would get the same result than Brak. Thanks guys! I really appreciate your help !

Comment: @BrakNicku I suggest you to create an own answer which can be accepted (cus the OP uses your formula at the end) ;)

Answer (score 2):

I too would recommend using a helper column. You don't need to use array formulas to get to the answer though. You can use the following in the next available column:

```
=IF(F66="Closed",IFERROR(D66/SUMIFS($D$66:$D$86,$F$66:$F$86,"Partial Sold",$C$66:$C$86,C66),0),0)
```

This will return values for everything that matches your criteria, and zeroes for everything else. Then you can just take the sum of this helper column as your final summation of rates.

[image: Excel]

If you *really* don't want to use a helper column, you can wrap the helper column formula in a `SUM` and swap out the individual cell references for arrays (i.e. swap `F66` for `$F$66:$F$86`, and so on), then enter it as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. The whole thing would look like this:

```
=SUM(IF($F$66:$F$86="Closed",IFERROR($D$66:$D$86/SUMIFS($D$66:$D$86,$F$66:$F$86,"Partial Sold",$C$66:$C$86,$C$66:$C$86),0),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see this being done without a helper column. In an unused column to the right of F66, put this array¹ formula.

```
=IF(AND(OR(C66=INDEX(C$66:C$86*(F$66:F$86="Partial Sold"), , )), F66="Closed"), D66/INDEX(D$66:D$86, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$21)/((C$66:C$86=C66)*(F$66:F$86="Partial Sold")), 1)), "")
```

Fill down as necessary. The result will be the sum of those 'helper' numbers.

[image: helper_sum_column]

Even if this could be done in a single formula, the calculation overhead would likely be prohibitive. Splitting a portion of the array calculations off to a helper column that can directly reference the value in column C for another lookup reduces this significantly.

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

Comment: As my Excel version is a little bit old I do not have the useful function AGGREGATE. Let me ask you, what is the difference if I use this formula instead of yours?  `=IF(AND(OR(C66=INDEX(C$66:C$86*(F$66:F$86="Partial Sold"),,)),F66="Closed"),D66/SUMIFS(D$66:D$86,C$66:C$86,C66,F$66:F$86,"Partial Sold"),"")`  I hope formatting will be ok now...

Comment: *I do not see this being done without a helper column.* -> **challenge accomplished** :P